# Hybrid classical-quantum linear solver based on the Neumann-Ulam method

Tags: qiskit

I read [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.10949.pdf) on quantum linear solver based on the Neumann-Ulam method ([here is a lesson about it](https://www.uzh.ch/cmsssl/physik/dam/jcr:ef32021d-9752-4a23-a310-35c879dbe49f/lec8.pdf)). But the article has not a lot of details. Therefore I don't understand what is the algorithm apart from the quantum walk.

Does somebody have an implementation of it ?